# Преобразовать двумерный массив в объект

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Есть двумерный массив Array = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
Нужно получить объект вида {1:2,3:4,5:6}
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать минимальным кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getObject = data => data
  .reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj[0]] = obj[1];
    return acc;
  }, {})

console.log(getObject([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное всё работает. 
Немного под себя подправил - слабоват я пока ещё в кодинге.
var data =  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]; 
var getObject = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj[0]] = obj[1];
  return acc;
  }, {})

console.log(getObject);

Comment: `const getObject = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ((acc[key] = val), acc), {});`